# Jasper Report -- Resource not found

Tags: php, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am developing a jasper report in PHP 
I have tried embedded jasper library 0.9d -- PhpJasperLibrary-master
After fixing part of the code in the library,
It works normally but it cannot display table format which is very important for me to develop Jasper report so I give up in this method and build up an jasper server.

I have installed the PHP Client(v2.0) by composer and using the sample code in the following link

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/php-client-sample-code
http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/php-client/releases

I am not sure why there is a lot of bugs in the sample code like getjob(s) function and passing variable to class client.

Anyway, I fixed it and the server info can be called.
In the last stage, I cannot run the report and the error message shown that the resource of my report not found.

```
Jaspersoft\Exception\RESTRequestException

Resource /20150604 not found.
```

I could like you to help me and I hope I can release a prefect version after all parts done.Thanks

And the below is my report information.

I have put my report under the folder /reports
and it can run in the jasper server

I have checked the URL that calling the report is like below

```
localhost:9090/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/20150604.html
```

I have concern about the URL but I cant find any reference to it.
So please support me to fix the problem.
Thanks

additional: here is the code I call the report

```
$report = $c->reportService()->runReport('/20150604', 'html');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm the rest endpoint to "run" a report is js/rest_v2/?path to report?.html

Unless your report is in the root of your organization, then you need a path.

Check out this (line 20):
https://github.com/jasonhuber/Jaspersoft_InputControlsFromCSV/blob/master/index.html#L20

and check in the web services guide page 71...

Comment: the actual report path to call is same as below if under report folder

localhost:9090/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/20150604.html

Comment: Assuming you mean reports folder and not report folder (otherwise that /reports/reports looks redundant right)?

Comment: actually I think the first /reports/ represent the folder name in the jasper server but it is NOT. 
the first /report/ is required even you dont have the folder "report" in the server

Comment: No. That is the rest endpoint: localhost:9090/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/ Anything you have after that is your path to your report. Check out the github link I posted line 32 now. /reports/ is the rest endpoint. It will be the same on every JRS everywhere. You repeated reports twice. That is why I made the comment about being redundant. Now you mention /report/ which is not used by JRS but could be a folder you created manually. Your URI would then be localhost:9090/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/report/somereport where the /report/somereport is something you created.